# How to pass a value to nested model by javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have a nested model with some value I want to pass it's value to controller by ajax call, i can send data fields of main model but i can't send data of nested model which are declare in model.

```
/****Model Code ******/
    public class xyzmodel()
    {
      public xyzmodel()
      {  
        address = new Addresmodel();
      }

      public int Id{set; get;}
      public string Name {set; get;}   

    }

    public class Addresmodel()
    {
       public string Address{set; get;}
       public string Number{set; get;}
    }
```

Now i have a controller

```
/***** Controller Action *****/

 public JsonResult SavePricingSet(xyzmodel model)
{

}
```

/ I am try to send value to this action method by javascript /

```
 function Data()
{
   Id: $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Id)').val(),
   Name : $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Name)').val(),
  /**** Above ID and Name Value i can send to controller and it's also receive ***/

 Address.Number : $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Address.Number)').val(),
/*** I can Get this Address.Number Value ****/ 
}
```

my question is that how can i send this type of nested model fields value

please give hint or idea

Regards,
Ajisha

Comment: Your xyzmodel doesn't have an "address" property.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting you, see there is addrerss.number now actully you can see model like this on  view page :- @model.address.number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your address field has lower case `a`, but you're using upper case.

```
@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.address.Number)
```